# How to define a geometry field with Peewee Models

Tags: postgresql, postgis, peewee

I have looked at examples online on how to create a geometry field with peewee and this is what I came up with so far:

```
class GeometryField(Field):
    db_field = 'geometry'

    def db_value(self, value):
        return fn.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        return fn.ST_AsGeoJSON(value)
```

I have added this definition to a table like so:

```
class GeoJSON(BaseModel):

    geojson_id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    geometry = GeometryField()
```

Now, this thing wouldn't run and I don't understand what I missed to make it happen.
My aim is to manage insertions of geometric entities into the DB so that later I can make use of PostGIS to query based on locations.

The error I'm getting in the init phase:

> peewee.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "NOT" LINE 1:
> ...geojson_id" UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "geometry"  NOT NULL)

I init the table like so:

```
        GeoJSON.create_table("geojsons")
```

What did I miss here? Did I need to do anything else before this geometryfield can be used?
Is there a secret geom field that Peewee supports out of the box that I don't know about?

Comment: Does your database actually support a UUID field-type? You have to "install" the uuid-ossp extension to use UUID data-type in PG.

Comment: I solved the initial problem, @coleifer. It was PostGIS not installed. I did notice something else, though, which you might help me with. Why doesn't the python_value() method doesn't actually return the value as GeoJSON? It returns a function object instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the DB failed to install PostGIS and therefore didn't recognize the geometry field from the DB.
Once I fixed that and had the extension installed, the solution above worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming back to this question later. The Peewee Syntax has changed since version 3.0. `db_field` has changed to `field_type`.

So to get it working:

1. Make sure you install the PostGIS extension on your postgres database.
   `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
2. Create a custom field.

```
class GeometryField(Field):
    field_type = 'geometry'

    def db_value(self, value):
        return fn.ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        return fn.ST_AsGeoJSON(value)
```

3. Use the custom field in your model

```
class GeoJSON(BaseModel):
    geojson_id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    geometry = GeometryField()
```

[Peewee Docs](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html?highlight=custom%20field#creating-a-custom-field)