How to work with PosrgreSQL's point type in peewee?
How do I work with PostrgreSQL's geometric type point?
When I create the model code with pwiz, a point column is defined as column_name = UnknownField()  # point. When I try to read this field, I only get a db_schema.UnknownField with no data in it. When I try to write it, it writes a null value no matter what I assign to it.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057283/7465516 It seems like it is possible but not automatic to integrate this datatype into peewee
